# MySQL group by with where clause with having count greater than 1

Tags: mysql

This should be really simple I know, but for the life of me I can't get my query to do what I need.

I am looking to find all rows that are a certain status (`paid`) grouped by `ref` but only if there is more than 1 row found.

This is my sample table:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
| id  | deleted  | status   |  ref  |
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
|   1 |        0 | pending  | 10001 |
|   2 |        0 | paid     | 10001 |
|   3 |        0 | paid     | 10001 |
|   4 |        0 | paid     | 10002 |
|   5 |        1 | pending  | 10002 |
|   6 |        1 | paid     | 10002 |
|   7 |        0 | pending  | 10003 |
|   8 |        0 | paid     | 10003 |
|   9 |        0 | paid     | 10003 |
|  10 |        0 | paid     | 10003 |
|  11 |        0 | pending  | 10004 |
|  12 |        0 | paid     | 10004 |
|  13 |        1 | pending  | 10005 |
|  14 |        1 | paid     | 10005 |
|  15 |        1 | paid     | 10005 |
|  16 |        0 | paid     | 10005 |
|  17 |        0 | pending  | 10006 |
|  18 |        0 | paid     | 10006 |
|  19 |        0 | paid     | 10006 |
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
```

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `status` = 'paid'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(`ref`,0,5)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

I need to have it matching by SUBSTR due to `ref` sometimes containing appended numbers.

The problem is that my query is returning this:

```
+-----+----------+---------+-------+
| id  | deleted  | status  |  ref  |
+-----+----------+---------+-------+
|   2 |        0 | paid    | 10001 |
+-----+----------+---------+-------+
```

When I'd like it to be returning `ref`s `10001`, `10003` & `10006`.

Can anyone help me work out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `status` = 'paid'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(`ref`,1,5)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

The position-argument for SUBSTR starts with 1, not with 0.

Answer (score 8):

From SUBSTR doc:

> For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.

So try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `status` = 'paid'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(`ref`,1,5)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: And I was beat by 8 seconds.. :)

Comment: Thanx! Appreciate.. I did include the quote from the doc.. That was what costed me the 8 secs.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The query should be

```
SELECT * from order
WHERE status="paid"
GROUP BY SUBSTRING('ref',1,5)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce this query as :

```sql
SELECT * from order
WHERE status="paid"
GROUP BY ref
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: wouldn't that give results for deleted = 1 too ?